# Replacing char in strings

Tags: python, string, char

for the following code I am trying to delete first character of every word but my code only deletes the first character of the last word. How can I do something so all the first characters of every word gets deleted.

```
ejmin = "ej pj dj"
tfl = [0,]   
nw = ''

for i in range(len(ejmin)):
      if ejmin[i] == ' ':
         i = i + 1
         tfl.append(i)

for i in tfl:
      nw = ejmin.replace(ejmin[i], "")
print nw
```

Comment: I edited my answer check it please.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with your code, but the key one for the purposes of your bug is that each time through the loop you assign to `nw`, overwriting all previous assignments to it.  So, of course, only the **last** assignment matters!

Just fixing that will only keep exposing further and further layers of bugs -- it's amazing how many issues you managed to pack into such a small piece of code.  For example, if you assigned to `ejmin` instead of to `nw`, that would break all the further-on indices.  Moreover, `ejmin.replace(ejmin[i]` does not replace "the char at position `i`" -- it replaces **every occurrence** of a character equal to that one.  &c -- this code as it stands is nearly unsalvageable.

Better rewrite it from scratch based on the core idea that strings are immutable (so applying multiple edits to a string is fraught), while lists are mutable (so such editing is fine).  So make your string into a list at the start, edit it, make it back into a string when done:

```
ejmin = "ej pj dj"
aslist = list(ejmin)
aslist[0] = ''
for i, c in enumerate(aslist):
    if c == ' ': aslist[i] = ''
nw = ''.join(aslist)
```

Comment: so how can i replace first char of every word? i understand what the bug is but idk how to fix the problem

Comment: @EjminMehranian, I edited the answer to list a few more of the actual and potential issues with your code (beyond the one I first highlighted) and also to explain a very different, much simpler approach, based on the core fact that strings are immutable, lists mutable -- take a look!

Answer (score 0):

```
ejmin = "ej pj dj"
a=ejmin.split() #split it by space 
for x in a:
    t=x[1:] #slicing it from first character to end of word
    print (t)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
j
j
j
>>>
```

Splitting them by space character, and slicing from first character.

Edit:

```
ejmin = "ej pj dj"
a=ejmin.split()
for x in a:
    z=x[0]
    h=x+z
    print (h)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
eje
pjp
djd
>>>
```

Comment: this word the problem is i need to save those characters because i am trying to add them to the end of the word as in if the sentence is "hello world how" i am trying to make the program write "elloh orldw owh"

Comment: @EjminMehranian, you're now suddenly revealing that your actual problem is very different (likely making the best answer very different too) -- **very** bad stack-overflow etiquette.  Deal with this Q **as you posed it**, and open another one for what you actually want to solve but decided not to tell us at the start!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried it by slicing

```
ejmin = "ej pj dj"
for word in ejmin.split():
    print word[1:],
```